# Remove nested newline characters in delimited file?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have a caret-delimited file. The only carets in the file are delimiters -- there are none in text. Several of the fields are free text fields and contain embedded newline characters. This makes parsing the file very difficult. I need the newline characters at the end of the records, but I need to remove them from the fields with text.

This is open source maritime piracy data from the [Global Integrated Shipping Information System](http://gisis.imo.org/Public/Default.aspx). Here are three records, preceded by the header row. In the first, the boat name is NORMANNIA, in the second, it is "Unkown" and in the third, it is KOTA BINTANG.

```
ship_name^ship_flag^tonnage^date^time^imo_num^ship_type^ship_released_on^time_zone^incident_position^coastal_state^area^lat^lon^incident_details^crew_ship_cargo_conseq^incident_location^ship_status_when_attacked^num_involved_in_attack^crew_conseq^weapons_used_by_attackers^ship_parts_raided^lives_lost^crew_wounded^crew_missing^crew_hostage_kidnapped^assaulted^ransom^master_crew_action_taken^reported_to_coastal_authority^reported_to_which_coastal_authority^reporting_state^reporting_intl_org^coastal_state_action_taken
NORMANNIA^Liberia^24987^2009-09-19^22:30^9142980^Bulk carrier^^^Off Pulau Mangkai,^^South China Sea^3° 04.00' N^105° 16.00' E^Eight pirates armed with long knives and crowbars boarded the ship underway. They broke into 2/O cabin, tied up his hands and threatened him with a long knife at his throat. Pirates forced the 2/O to call the Master. While the pirates were waiting next to the Master’s door, they seized C/E and tied up his hands. The pirates rushed inside the Master’s cabin once it was opened. They threatened him with long knives and crowbars and demanded money. Master’s hands were tied up and they forced him to the aft station. The pirates jumped into a long wooden skiff with ship’s cash and crew personal belongings and escaped. C/E and 2/O managed to free themselves and raised the alarm^Pirates tied up the hands of Master, C/E and 2/O. The pirates stole ship’s cash and master’s, C/E & 2/O cash and personal belongings^In international waters^Steaming^5-10 persons^Threat of violence against the crew^Knives^^^^^^^^SSAS activated and reported to owners^^Liberian Authority^^ICC-IMB Piracy Reporting Centre Kuala Lumpur^-
Unkown^Marshall Islands^19846^2013-08-28^23:30^^General cargo ship^^^Cam Pha Port^Viet Nam^South China Sea^20° 59.92' N^107° 19.00' E^While at anchor, six robbers boarded the vessel through the anchor chain and cut opened the padlock of the door to the forecastle store. They removed the turnbuckle and lashing of the forecastle store's rope hatch. The robbers escaped upon hearing the alarm activated when they were sighted by the 2nd officer during the turn-over of duty watch keepers.^"There was no injury to the crew however, the padlock of the door to the forecastle store and the rope hatch were cut-opened.

Two centre shackles and one end shackle were stolen"^In port area^At anchor^5-10 persons^^None/not stated^Main deck^^^^^^^-^^^Viet Nam^"ReCAAP ISC via ReCAAP Focal Point (Vietnam)

ReCAAP ISC via Focal Point (Singapore)"^-
KOTA BINTANG^Singapore^8441^2002-05-12^15:55^8021311^Bulk carrier^^UTC^^^South China Sea^^^Seven robbers armed with long knives boarded the ship, while underway. They broke open accommodation door, held hostage a crew member and forced the Master to open his cabin door. They then tied up the Master and crew member, forced them back onto poop deck from where the robbers jumped overboard and escaped in an unlit boat^Master and cadet assaulted; Cash, crew belongings and ship's cash stolen^In territorial waters^Steaming^5-10 persons^Actual violence against the crew^Knives^^^^^^2^^-^^Yes. SAR, Djakarta and Indonesian Naval Headquarters informed^^ICC-IMB PRC Kuala Lumpur^-
```

You'll notice that the first and third records are fine and easy to parse. The second record, "Unkown," has some nested newline characters.

How should I go about removing the nested newline characters (but not those at the end of the records) in a python script (or otherwise, if there's an easier way) so that I can import this data into SAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by counting the number of delimiters encountered and manually switching to a new record when I reached the number associated with a single record. I then stripped all of the newline characters and wrote the data back out to a new file. In essence, it's the original file with the newline characters stripped from the fields but with a newline character at the end of each record. Here's the code:

```
f = open("events.csv", "r")

carets_per_record = 33

final_file = []
temp_file  = []
temp_str   = ''
temp_cnt   = 0

building   = False

for i, line in enumerate(f):

    # If there are no carets on the line, we are building a string
    if line.count('^') == 0:
        building = True

    # If we are not building a string, then set temp_str equal to the line
    if building is False:
        temp_str = line
    else:
        temp_str = temp_str + " " + line

    # Count the number of carets on the line
    temp_cnt = temp_str.count('^')

    # If we do not have the proper number of carets, then we are building
    if temp_cnt < carets_per_record:
        building = True

    # If we do have the proper number of carets, then we are finished
    # and we can push this line to the list
    elif temp_cnt == carets_per_record:
        building = False
        temp_file.append(temp_str)

# Strip embedded newline characters from the temp file
for i, item in enumerate(temp_file):
    final_file.append(temp_file[i].replace('\n', ''))

# Write the final_file list out to a csv final_file
g = open("new_events.csv", "wb")


# Write the lines back to the file
for item in enumerate(final_file):
    # item is a tuple, so we get the content part and append a new line
     g.write(item[1] + '\n')

# Close the files we were working with
f.close()
g.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

load the data into a string a then do

```
import re
newa=re.sub('\n','',a)
```

and there will be no newlines in newa

```
newa=re.sub('\n(?!$)','',a)
```

and it leaves the ones at the end of the line but strips the rest

Comment: Will that not remove the end of record newlines, too?

Comment: I tried your second example and it removes the newline characters at the end of lines, too -- not just embedded ones.

Answer (score 2):

I see you've tagged this as regex, but I would recommend using the builtin CSV library to parse this. The CSV library will parse the file correctly, keeping newlines where it should.

Python CSV Examples: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: I agree, the csv library is easy to use and seems to suit your problem

Comment: Well, what I really need is a csv file without the linebreaks in fields so that I can import it into SAS. It actually seems like the regex method of removing those line breaks would be fewer steps. How would you handle re-exporting the data back to csv, after parsing it, to get a well-formatted csv file? Some of the internal text fields have embedded quotation marks, too, while others don't.

Comment: @Clay: Perhaps you can upload an example file to a gist, and we can show you how to parse it as CSV with the csv module, then reoutput it correctly. What you really need is to field quotation, which your input doesn't seem to contain.

Comment: The issue with the free text in the data is that some of it is quoted writ large (entire block is a quote) and some of it contains nested quotes that actually are quotes and need to be maintained as quotes. The `^` was used as a delimiter because it appeared nowhere in the entire corpus of the data. I worked through the problem using another technique that I'll update to the original question.